# Lookup and match from multiple collections MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to be able to $lookup multiple collections and $match each collection.

I want to to match on `player.player_name`.

And I want to match on `player.team.team_name`.

I don't want to have the second match filter from the first match though, which is what I have right now.

I want the two lookups/matches to add to each other.

```
Report.aggregate(
            [
                {
                    "$lookup": {
                        from: Player.collection.name,
                        localField: "player",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "player"
                    }
                },
                { "$match": { "player.player_name": { "$in": players } } },
                {
                    "$lookup": {
                        from: Team.collection.name,
                        localField: "player.team",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "player.team"
                    }
                },
               { "$match": { "player.team.team_name": { "$in": team } } }
            ]
        )
```

For example, I have this data

```
{
     player: {
             player_name: 'Gerrit Cole'
             team:
                  {
                       team_name: 'Astros'
                  }
          }
},
{
     player: {
             player_name: 'Daniel Jones'
             team:
                  {
                       team_name: 'Giants'
                  }
          }
}
```

If I matched for player_name Gerrit Cole and team_name Giants, I need it to return both records.

EDIT:

This is a sample Player record:

```
{
    _id: 5d3737f4d75f910eb785125f,
    player_name: 'Yordan Alvarez',
    player_position: 'Designated Hitter',
    team: 5d30c5b423226e0ddc684b4e,
    createdAt: 2019-07-23T16:38:12.801Z,
    updatedAt: 2019-07-23T16:38:12.801Z,
    __v: 0
  }
```

This is a sample team record:

```
{
    _id: 5d372e22d75f910eb78511c7,
    team_name: 'Titans',
    city_or_state: 'Tennessee',
    league: 5d24c392d0a52545e8a345b1,
    createdAt: 2019-07-23T15:56:18.304Z,
    updatedAt: 2019-07-23T15:56:18.304Z,
    __v: 0
  }
```

Comment: You have posted end results, please post at least a sample record for both collections

Comment: @ersnh I edited the post to give sample records for both collections

Comment: You are aggregating on Report collection, and not player or team collection. Is that a 3rd collection you are mapping?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find anything related to Reports collection which you have used in your query example. Based on the 2 sample records for `team` and `player` collection, following query should work. You do not need to use 2 `lookup`, rather need one `unwind` operation.

```
db.player.aggregate([{
    "$lookup": {
        from: "team",
        localField: "team",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "team"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$team"
}, {
    $match: {
        $or: [{
                "player_name": {
                    "$in": players
                }
            },
            {
                "team.team_name": {
                    "$in": teams
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}])
```